# How can I separate the callback logic in the one single file using codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I use the config.php to store all the form_validation rules...But I would like to store the callback function in one single file too, how can I do so? Any ideas? Thank you....

Now my file is something like this:

User_controller 
under user controller have many customized callback_valid , but I ready move all the rules in the config.php. I would like to put the _valid callback to one class. Thank you .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the Form_validation lib uses it's `$CI` property to see if the callback method exists. Normally this looks at the current controller. However, you can change this behavior by extending the validation class and altering the `run()` method.

```
class MY_Form_validation extends CI_Form_validation {

    /**
     * Support for validation callbacks from any object
     * 
     * @access      public
     * @param       object      The object to run callbacks from
     * @param       string      Is there a validation rule for the particular URI being accessed?
     * @return      bool        Validation status
     */
    function run($obj = '', $group = '')
    { 
        // Assign the callback object
        if (is_object($obj)) $this->CI =& $obj;

        // Run the validation as normal
        return parent::run($group);
    }

}
```

We're just reassigning the `$CI` property. So to use callbacks from a class called `user_validation` for instance, you can do this:

```
$callback_class = $this->user_validation;
if ($this->form_validation->run($callback_class)) {}
```

Any loaded class will work, so you can store callback rules in models or libraries, just pass the object you want to handle callbacks with to the `run()` method.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do in this case is just create a MY_Form_validation class to extend CodeIgniter's form validation.  Place the "_valid" checks in the newly created MY_Form_Validation file and set the rules for the "_valid" checks the same way that you do for the default form_validation rules.

Something like...

```
class MY_Form_validation extends CI_Form_validation {

    function valid_user($str)
    {

    } 

    function valid_password($str)
    {

    }  
}
```